# Is EntityFieldQuery as sophisticated as the Database API?

Tags: database

I was wondering if `EntityFieldQuery` is just a layer of abstraction on top of the database query builder. For example can I use `addExpression` and `isNotNull` in an `EntityFieldQuery`, for example?

Or, is it separate and not as sophisticated.

Comment: If you're looking for more from efq try my sandbox https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mikeytown2/2209909

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering if EntityFieldQuery is just a layer of abstraction on top of the database query builder.

Yes, that's exactly what it is. It's not subclass of `SelectQuery` or anything higher up the chain, though.

> For example can I use addExpression and isNotNull in an EntityFieldQuery, for example?

No, EFQ doesn't implement those methods. You can see what methods are available by looking at the [source](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).

> Or, is it separate and not as sophisticated.

Yes it's separate, "not as sophisticated" can't really apply since the functional differences between EFQ and a `SelectQuery` are intentional. They're not supposed to do the same thing, an EFQ is intentionally limited to functionality that makes sense for entities only.

However, an EFQ will eventually run a `SelectQuery` anyway, which you can alter just like any other query. So you can make it as "sophisticated" as you need to.